# Successfully installed georasters but unable to import

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, gdal, libtiff, geotiff

Not able to solve.Kindly clarify.

I had installed `georasters` then it gave error with `numpy` ,now `numpy` is solved it is giving error with `fiona`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import georasters
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\georasters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .georasters import get_geo_info, map_pixel, map_pixel_inv, aggregate, create_geotiff, align_rasters, \
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\georasters\georasters.py", line 38, in <module>
    from fiona.crs import from_string
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Having same issue.

Just install `fiona` and `geopandas`.

```
pip install fiona geopandas
```